# using os.popen3() to extract thumbnail for a video in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, ffmpeg, popen

I am using ffmpeg to extract a frame from a video. This works fine when I use ffmpeg from the command line, however, when I try to do the same thing using the python:

```
os.popen3('ffmpeg -i videoPath -an -ss 00:00:02 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y picturePath')
```

I have no idea on how to get the extracted image. So far, I get only text saying (ffmpeg version N-62039-gc00f368 Copyright (c) 2000....) which is what I see in the command line. Would you please guide through what I need to do to get the image extracted. Thank you.

Comment: How do you get the extracted image when you run ffmpeg from the command line?

Comment: Yes, that what I want, if possible of course..

Comment: It is not a yes or no question :) What do you mean when you say: *"this works fine when I use ffmpeg from the command line"*? Unrelated: [Making GIFs From Video Files With Python](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/)

Comment: I can get video thumbnails using the ffmpeg from a command line, I find the PNG ina  folder, but what I want to execute the ffmpeg from Python and get the PNG as a return value so I can use it further.

Comment: Do you need help to run the command (to create a png file) or do you need help to load already saved png-file to be edited in Python? `moviepy` module I've linked above combines both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use the following function for that sort of tasks. It includes a timeout parameter for automatically aborting excessively long running processes. That's often handy when it comes to user uploaded content:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Timer

def run_with_timeout(cmd, sec):
    def kill_proc(p, killed):
        killed['val'] = True
        p.kill()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    killed = {'val': False}
    timer = Timer(sec, kill_proc, [p, killed])
    timer.start()
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    timer.cancel()
    return p.returncode, stdout, stderr, killed['val']
```

With that, you can simply call any shell command with options, which is run synchronously. That means the function waits until the process is finished. Therefore, when the function is done, the thumbnail is either created or an error is returned:

```
videoPath = '/path/to/video/source/file.mp4'
picturePath = '/path/to/output.jpg'
result = run_with_timeout(['ffmpeg', '-i', videoPath, '-an', '00:00:02', '-r', '1', '-vframes', '1', '-y', picturePath], 30)
if result[0] != 0:
    print 'error'
else:
    print 'success'
    # do something with videoPath
```

Works in current Python versions 2.7.x.

Answer (score 0):

os is deprecated. You should use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: The `os` module is not deprecated, but `os.popen*()` and related functions are.

Comment: Still, doesn't answer the question of how to get the image back to code so I can use it further. I have tried using subprocess too..